# Content in card layout does not shrink in mobile view

Tags: html, flexbox, responsiveness, tailwind-css

I just got started with **Tailwind CSS**. And I am trying to make some **card layout**( with VG icons and text on each ) **responsive** with **flexbox**. When I resize the screen it does **shrink** well until it hits the **sm screen**. Then only circa **60%** of the **card height** is visible.

I am not sure if I should make the content of the card e.g the icon and the text smaller for mobile or should it shrink down automatically?

Here is my code:

```
<main class="h-screen-90 flex flex-col items-center h-64">
            <div>
                <h1 class="text-center text-4xl lg:text-5xl text-white font-normal">no-more spending hours
                    <br> on desk research or
                    <br>Powerpoint visuals</h1>
                <hr class="w-48 border-t-4 border-red-light">
                <h3 class="text-center text-2xl text-white font-medium">Do what you do. Best</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="inline-flex flex-col md:flex-row mt-auto justify-center">
                <div class="flex-auto text-center mx-4 my-4 md:my-0 pt-24 px-8 max-w-sm rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg bg-purple-darker">
                    <i class="fas fa-chalkboard text-white text-6xl"></i>
                    <div class="py-12">
                        <div class="text-white font-bold text-xl">BUSINESS PRESENTATIONS</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-auto text-center mx-4 my-4 md:my-0 pt-24 px-14 max-w-sm rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg bg-teal">
                    <i class="fas fa-search text-white text-6xl"></i>
                    <div class="py-12">
                        <div class="text-center text-white font-bold text-xl">BUSINESS RESEARCH
                            <br>SERVICES</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-auto text-center mx-4 my-4 md:my-0 pt-24 px-7 max-w-sm rounded overflow-hidden shadow-lg bg-red-light ">
                    <i class="fas fa-brush text-white text-6xl"></i>
                    <div class="py-12">
                        <div class="text-center text-white font-bold text-xl">UNLIMITED OFF-THE-RACK
                            <br>DESIGNER SLIDES</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
```